# Real-time notifications and messages ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

This is my first time building a real-time notifications and messages. Could you give me some good practices about this ? The obvious choice of technology is SignalR, but what is the best way to approach this ? Is it better to keep the updates in memory by keeping every connected user in a dictionary knowing my users will not be more than 6000-7000, or is it better to use sqldependency ? Are there other ways to approach this particular problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"good practices...best way"_ - Your question is arguably _primarily opinion-based_ as well as perhaps _too broad_ which if the case, off-topic for SO.  [ask]. Wishing you well

Comment: Signal-R can take this load, `Max concurrent requests per application`: Increasing the number of concurrent IIS requests will increase server resources available for serving requests. The default value is 5000; refer more for here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance